# Automatically resize form and move controls when new ones are added or a text in a label grows

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, autoresize

Beginner in Visual Studio here.

I'm trying to create an C# Windows Form application that simply displays a form to show some information about the local system.

I have created this form with the help of the VS designer:

[image]

As you can see, it consists of a simple panel with a PictureBox at the top, a label below it (both centered), three table layouts next to each other, and a button at the bottom. Never mind the label texts.

The rows of all the table layouts are set to absolute, this is because I want to programatically add rows to the end middle and right table layout if there are more than one local IP address in the computer and setting the rows to auto size or percentage would make alignment difficult if more rows are added.

Now, my problem is that I can't figure out how to make the form resize and move the controls (specifically move the 'OK' button down) when more rows are added.

I have tried anchoring the button to the bottom edge of the form as well as the bottom of the middle table, both produce the same result: the button stays where it is and the new rows overlap it, like this

[image]

I would also like to know how to have the form resize to fit the contents of the labels. For example, if the text in one of the labels inside the layout is bigger than the column width, I'd like to have the form grow to accommodate it. Likewise, I'd like the form to shrink to fit the largest text.

I realize that this may not be the most efficient or easiest way to create this particular form, but it is what I've come up with, I of course welcome any suggestions in that regard. It is important to maintain alignment between the rows of all table layouts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data grid and add controls to it if an add button is pressed. You can scroll through the rows so you won't need to adjust the height of the form